# Solr - Boosting field value dynamically based on popularity score

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a product SOLR document with some of the following values:

```
id: '...'
model: '44758514',
name: '...',
category: '...',
price: 23.25,
popularity: '0.123'
```

And so on. Now, the list is queried upon and the result is sorted by the "score".

Here comes my question. I have a list of models and scores that i wish to project into my SOLR query when searching for my data. The list looks like this:

```
{ model: 44758514, score: 1.352398 },
{ model: 51148767, score: 1.160451 }
```

I wish to boost the calculated "score" value, or boost the "popularity" field with the fixed values from my list above, that matches the model number, so that i can sort by the "new" and accumulated value.

I read about the "bf" boost function queries, but i could not find an example that describes how to go about it when you need to boost a value of a field with a dynamic value on specific documents.

Did anyone do this before?

Comment: Have you seen the examples here? https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/the-dismax-query-parser.html#bq-boost-query-parameter

Comment: Actually it seems like I could use boost queries to achieve what I need. I tried adding model:<id>^<score> and it seems to boost the score correctly.